# javascript group on an array of objects with timestamp range difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, timestamp, grouping

## javascript group on an array of objects with timestamp range difference

> I want to group the messages objects of the array by within a five minutes timestamp range.

1. src data

```js
let msgs = [
    {
      "msgId": 606896983568064500,
      "text": "B",
      "time": "2019/08/02 17:11",
      "count": 1,
      "isSelf": true
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606897486704189400,
      "text": "A",
      "time": "2019/08/02 17:13",
      "count": 2,
      "isSelf": true
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606892034444533800,
      "text": "C",
      "time": "2019/08/02 16:52",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606889698041045000,
      "text": "D",
      "time": "2019/08/02 16:42",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606866947376980000,
      "text": "E",
      "time": "2019/08/02 15:12",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606866947376970000,
      "text": "G",
      "time": "2019/08/01 5:12",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606866947376910000,
      "text": "F",
      "time": "2019/08/01 15:12",
      "count": 3
    },
];
```

2. wanted result

> timestamp by `ASC` order

```js
DB groups = {
    "0": [
        {
            "msgId": 606866947376970000,
            "text": "G",
            "time": "2019/08/01 5:12",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "1": [
        {
            "msgId": 606866947376910000,
            "text": "F",
            "time": "2019/08/01 15:12",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "msgId": 606866947376980000,
            "text": "E",
            "time": "2019/08/02 15:12",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "msgId": 606889698041045000,
            "text": "D",
            "time": "2019/08/02 16:42",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "4": [
        {
            "serialNum": "C 1564735983212",
            "msgId": 606892034444533800,
            "text": "C",
            "time": "2019/08/02 16:52",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "5": [
        {
            "msgId": 606896983568064500,
            "text": "B",
            "time": "2019/08/02 17:11",
            "count": 1,
            "isSelf": true
        },
        {
            "msgId": 606897486704189400,
            "text": "A",
            "time": "2019/08/02 17:13",
            "count": 2,
            "isSelf": true
        }
    ],
}
```

> got result

```js
DB groups = {
    "0": [
        {
            "msgId": 606866947376910000,
            "text": "F",
            "time": "2019/08/01 15:12",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "1": [
        {
            "msgId": 606866947376970000,
            "text": "G",
            "time": "2019/08/01 5:12",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "msgId": 606866947376980000,
            "text": "E",
            "time": "2019/08/02 15:12",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "msgId": 606889698041045000,
            "text": "D",
            "time": "2019/08/02 16:42",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "4": [
        {
            "msgId": 606892034444533800,
            "text": "C",
            "time": "2019/08/02 16:52",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "5": [
        {
            "msgId": 606896983568064500,
            "text": "B",
            "time": "2019/08/02 17:11",
            "count": 1,
            "isSelf": true
        },
        {
            "msgId": 606897486704189400,
            "text": "A",
            "time": "2019/08/02 17:13",
            "count": 2,
            "isSelf": true
        }
    ],
    "6": [
        {
            "msgId": 606896983568064500,
            "text": "B",
            "time": "2019/08/02 17:11",
            "count": 1,
            "isSelf": true
        },
        {
            "msgId": 606897486704189400,
            "text": "A",
            "time": "2019/08/02 17:13",
            "count": 2,
            "isSelf": true
        }
    ]
}
```

3. my solution with duplicate group bug

[image]

```js
let log = console.log;

// asc & ascending
msgs.sort((a, b) => (a.msgId > b.msgId) ? 1 : -1);

log(`msgs =`, JSON.stringify(msgs, null, 4));

// mm, ss, ms
const fiveMinutes = 5 * 60 * 1000;

let DB = {};
let len = msgs.length;

let groupFlag = ``;
if (msgs[0]) {
    groupFlag = Date.parse(msgs[0].time);
}

let cp_msgs = msgs;

let finished = false;

// group flag
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // filter
    let new_cp_msgs = cp_msgs.filter(
        (obj, k) => {
            let {
                time,
            } = obj;
            if (time.includes(`/`)) {
                time = Date.parse(time);
            } else {
                let today = autoGetToday(time);
                time = Date.parse(today);
            }
            let min = Math.abs(groupFlag - time);
            if (min <= fiveMinutes) {
                // DB[i].push(obj);
            } else {
                return obj;
            }
        }
    );
    if (cp_msgs.length <= 1 && finished) {
        break;
    } else {
        DB[i] = [];
    }
    log(`cp_msgs =`, cp_msgs);
    for (let j = 0; j < cp_msgs.length; j++) {
        if (cp_msgs.length === 1) {
            finished = true;
        }
        let obj = cp_msgs[j];
        let {
            time,
        } = obj;
        if (time.includes(`/`)) {
            time = Date.parse(time);
        } else {
            let today = autoGetToday(time);
            time = Date.parse(today);
        }
        let min = Math.abs(time - groupFlag);
        if (min <= fiveMinutes) {
            DB[i].push(obj);
        } else {
            groupFlag = time;
            cp_msgs = new_cp_msgs;
            break;
        }
    }
}

const autoGetToday = (time = ``, debug = false) => {
    let log = console.log;
    let date = new Date();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let day = date.getDate();
    if (debug) {
        log(year);
        log(month);
        log(day);
    }
    let today = `${year}/${month}/${day} ${time}`;
    if (debug) {
        log(`today =`, today);
    }
    return today;
};

console.log(`DB groups =`, JSON.stringify(DB, null, 4));
```

> repl

```js
let msgs = [
    {
      "msgId": 606896983568064500,
      "text": "B",
      "time": "2019/08/02 17:11",
      "count": 1,
      "isSelf": true
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606897486704189400,
      "text": "A",
      "time": "2019/08/02 17:13",
      "count": 2,
      "isSelf": true
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606892034444533800,
      "text": "C",
      "time": "2019/08/02 16:52",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606889698041045000,
      "text": "D",
      "time": "2019/08/02 16:42",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606866947376980000,
      "text": "E",
      "time": "2019/08/02 15:12",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606866947376970000,
      "text": "G",
      "time": "2019/08/01 5:12",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "msgId": 606866947376910000,
      "text": "F",
      "time": "2019/08/01 15:12",
      "count": 3
    },
];

let log = console.log;

// asc & ascending
msgs.sort((a, b) => (a.msgId > b.msgId) ? 1 : -1);

log(`msgs =`, JSON.stringify(msgs, null, 4));

// mm, ss, ms
const fiveMinutes = 5 * 60 * 1000;

let DB = {};
let len = msgs.length;

let groupFlag = ``;
if (msgs[0]) {
    groupFlag = Date.parse(msgs[0].time);
}

let cp_msgs = msgs;

let finished = false;

// group flag
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // filter
    let new_cp_msgs = cp_msgs.filter(
        (obj, k) => {
            let {
                time,
            } = obj;
            if (time.includes(`/`)) {
                time = Date.parse(time);
            } else {
                let today = autoGetToday(time);
                time = Date.parse(today);
            }
            let min = Math.abs(groupFlag - time);
            if (min <= fiveMinutes) {
                // DB[i].push(obj);
            } else {
                return obj;
            }
        }
    );
    if (cp_msgs.length <= 1 && finished) {
        break;
    } else {
        DB[i] = [];
    }
    log(`cp_msgs =`, cp_msgs);
    for (let j = 0; j < cp_msgs.length; j++) {
        if (cp_msgs.length === 1) {
            finished = true;
        }
        let obj = cp_msgs[j];
        let {
            time,
        } = obj;
        if (time.includes(`/`)) {
            time = Date.parse(time);
        } else {
            let today = autoGetToday(time);
            time = Date.parse(today);
        }
        let min = Math.abs(time - groupFlag);
        if (min <= fiveMinutes) {
            DB[i].push(obj);
        } else {
            groupFlag = time;
            cp_msgs = new_cp_msgs;
            break;
        }
    }
}

const autoGetToday = (time = ``, debug = false) => {
    let log = console.log;
    let date = new Date();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let day = date.getDate();
    if (debug) {
        log(year);
        log(month);
        log(day);
    }
    let today = `${year}/${month}/${day} ${time}`;
    if (debug) {
        log(`today =`, today);
    }
    return today;
};

console.log(`DB groups =`, JSON.stringify(DB, null, 4));
```

4. right solution(looking for help...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/139300/cd wanted your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort the array in advance and get the delta of times for checking.

```js
var data = [{ msgId: 606896983568064500, text: "B", time: "2019/08/02 17:11", count: 1, isSelf: true }, { msgId: 606897486704189400, text: "A", time: "2019/08/02 17:13", count: 2, isSelf: true }, { serialNum: "C 1564735983212", msgId: 606892034444533700, text: "C", time: "2019/08/02 16:52", count: 3 }, { msgId: 606889698041045000, text: "D", time: "2019/08/02 16:42", count: 3 }, { msgId: 606866947376980000, text: "E", time: "2019/08/02 15:12", count: 3 }, { msgId: 606866947376970000, text: "G", time: "2019/08/01 5:12", count: 3 }, { msgId: 606866947376910000, text: "F", time: "2019/08/01 15:12", count: 3 }],
    result = data
        .sort((a, b) => new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time))
        .reduce((r, o, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => {
            if (!last || new Date(o.time) - new Date(last.time) > 5 * 60 * 1000) {
                r.push([o]);
            } else {
                r[r.length - 1].push(o);
            }
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(Object.assign({}, result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!
That's Array result is OK, but not the exactly Object result which I wanted.